# How to update multiple rows with subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to save the results of a subquery into a table.

```
select (b.close - a.close) AS difference from day_ohlcs AS a inner join day_ohlcs AS b ON a.id + 1 = b.id
```

The speed of the subquery is fast, but when I try to put it in an update statement it takes forever, so I know I'm doing something wrong.

```
UPDATE day_ohlcs
SET price_change = t.difference
FROM (select (b.close - a.close) AS difference
    FROM day_ohlcs AS a 
    inner join day_ohlcs AS b 
    ON a.id + 1 = b.id) 
AS t
WHERE day_ohlcs.instrument_id = 1;
```

What am I not understanding? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hm you make a tripple join for this table. If it is big, this can afect the performance.

Comment: I just want the difference of one column from one row to the next. Should I be trying to implement a window function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics are very different between the two queries. Note that day_ohlcs appears twice vs three times -- the latter does a great deal too many calculations, essentially calculating the difference for the entire table.

You can remove the unneeded behavior like so:

```
UPDATE day_ohlcs as a
SET price_change = b.close - a.close
FROM day_ohlcs AS b
WHERE a.id + 1 = b.id and a.instrument_id = 1;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Comment: How can I set the order for A? I got it to work with table b, but how can I do it with A?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you haven't specify column of `day_ohlcs` to join on, like:

```
UPDATE day_ohlcs
SET price_change = t.difference
FROM (select a.id, (b.close - a.close) AS difference
    FROM day_ohlcs AS a 
    inner join day_ohlcs AS b 
    ON a.id + 1 = b.id) 
AS t
WHERE day_ohlcs.instrument_id = 1 and day_ohlcs = t.id
```

Actually looks like you can do this without subquery

```
update day_ohlcs as a set
   price_change = b.close - a.close
from day_ohlcs as b 
where b.id = a.id + 1 and a.instrument_id = 1
```